# Stack Exchange gadget for Gmail and iGoogle

Tags: app, java

#### About

This handy gadget can be added to iGoogle or left-hand nav panel of any Gmail account.
It displays your current reputation on selected StackExchange sites and notifies you of reputation changes. Gadget supports all StackExchange sites.

#### Screenshots

*Gmail*
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
*iGoogle*
[image]
[image]

#### Access

[http://buttons.googlesyndication.com/fusion/add.gif](http://bit.ly/bd4DEq)

[Social gadgets](http://www.google.com/support/websearch/bin/answer.py?answer=145550&hl=en)

Gadget URLs
http://stackexchange-gadget.appspot.com/gadget/StackGoogleGadget.gadget.xml or https://stackexchange-gadget.appspot.com/gadget/StackGoogleGadget.gadget.xml

*Log in to Gmail.

Click 'Settings' near the top right of the Gmail page.

The Gmail settings page will appear. Click the 'Labs' tab.

The Gmail Labs page will appear. This is a laboratory area or testing ground where Google allows you to use experimental features in Gmail. Scroll down to find the feature called 'Add any gadget by URL'.
Select the 'Enable' radio button next to the 'Add any gadget by URL' feature, as shown here:*
[image]
*Click 'Save Changes' to enable the new feature.

A new 'Gadgets' tab will appear on your 'Settings' page. Click the 'Gadgets' tab.

The 'Gadgets' page will appear. Enter or paste gadget's URL (https://stackexchange-gadget.appspot.com/gadget/StackGoogleGadget.gadget.xml) into the 'Add a gadget by its URL' textbox then click the 'Add' button.
The gadget will appear in the left-hand panel of your Gmail page.

Start adding accounts*

#### Platform

Gmail and iGoogle gadget

#### Contact

Created by me (Vladislav Tserman) in spare time.
Leave your feedback and bug reports in comments.
I'm available at: vladjan (at) gmail.com

#### Code

Written in Java, Google Web Toolkit under Eclipse Helios. Powered by Google App Engine for Java. 
Objectify framework used for datastore instead of JPA/JDO.
Thanks to creators of StackWrap4J - a Java wrapper for the Stack Exchange API

#### Known issues

Gadget takes up a lot of space even if you only have a few accounts connected. Ability to shrink the box vertically should be added.

#### Future

I want to hear from the users and incorporate as much feedback as possible into the gadget.
**Any suggestions for improvements/features to add?**

Comment: When I add it to my iGoogle page, I get an error "Oops! Something went wrong: Can't get owner of the gadget. Please try to reload this gadget."

Comment: @George Gadget uses OpenSocial and it needs to have access to your Google public profile to know your user id. 
I think in iGoogle you should allow this gadget to:
Know who I am and see my Friends group. 
http://www.google.com/support/websearch/bin/answer.py?answer=145550&hl=en

Comment: It would be a great gadget if I would be able to make it work properly! I get an "Errors:504 Error" very often. I also cannot link to some account like scifi.stackexchange or programmers.stackexchange.

Comment: Could it be possible to make a release that allow me to add beta stackexchange accounts to it?

Answer (score 3):

**Gmail and iGoogle Gadget for Stack Exchange [v1.0.16 released!, now with user mentions]**
*Changelog v1.0.16*

- *New types of notifications added. Now
  Gadget notifies you on comments that
  are directed to you.*
- *Comments are
  expandable, so click on comment title
  will expand height to accommodate all
  available text.*
- *New updates are
  highlighted now.*
- *'Mark all as read'
  button added when there are new
  updates. It allows you to mark all
  updates as read.*
- *Improved UI*

**Browser restart required if you have this Gadget already installed**

*GMail*
[image]
[image]
[image]

*iGoogle*
[image]